# Unable to install Ubuntu 11.10 - CD with downloaded ISO file doesn't work

Tags: 11.10

I tried to install Ubuntu 11.10 on my DELL Studio XPS running with Windows 7 Professional. Following the recommended installation steps found on the internet, I first downloaded the ISO file, burned it on CD and restarted the system from this burned CD forced by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Nothing happened (black screen with blinking cursor) and after a while normal Windows 7 startup appeared. Finally I tried the 32bit as well as 64bit version with the same disappointing result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You may have burned the .iso file to the CD without actually burning the disk image to the disk.  When you open the CD in a folder in Windows, it should look like the CD contains multiple folders. If it looks like the disk contains a single .iso file, you'll need to try again.

Ubuntu's [community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) has good instructions for burning an iso to a disk. Assuming you're burning the CD in Windows:

1. Install the open source [Infra Recorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) software
2. With a blank disk in the drive, open Infra Recorder and click the *Burn Image* button
3. Choose the Ubuntu .iso file that you downloaded and burn that image to the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just have to set your CD/DVD drive as your first boot priority in your BIOS.

Getting to the BIOS config screen varies from motherboard to motherboard, but its ussually done by pressing either <kbd>DEL</kbd> or the <kbd>F2</kbd>, once there you should go into the *boot* section, and alter your boot priority to use the CD/DVD ROM drive as the primary boot device.

Answer (score 1):

The only other thing these guys haven't covered is making sure the md5sum is correct and not mismatched.

Take a look here for the proper check sums https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

I would also recommend burning at the slowest speed possible.